# Etymologie der Dialektwörter "Iadi" (Dienstag) und "Pfingsti" (Donnerstag)

Tags: etymology, dialect, austrian

[Mein Großvater](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_Sch%C3%B6lnast) war Heimatforscher und Mundartdichter und sehr mit der Sprache seiner Heimat, der Südoststeiermark = Vulkanland<sup>1</sup>, verbunden; und erst heute stieß ich beim Recherchieren zu anderen Fragen auf die Seite [mundart.vulkanland.at](http://www.mundart.vulkanland.at), auf der Forschungsergebnisse zu einer Studie der Dialekte im Vulkanland präsentiert wurden. Dabei fiel mir wieder ein, wie mein Großvater gerne die Namen der Wochentage in seinem Dialekt aufzählte. (Beginnend mit dem Wort für Montag, in der üblichen Reihenfolge):

> [Maudi](http://www.mundart.vulkanland.at/de/mundART_suche/?words=Montag), [Iadi](http://www.mundart.vulkanland.at/de/mundART_suche/?words=Dienstag), [Mitti](http://www.mundart.vulkanland.at/de/mundART_suche/?words=Mittwoch), [Pfingsti](http://www.mundart.vulkanland.at/de/mundART_suche/?words=Donnerstag), [Freiti](http://www.mundart.vulkanland.at/de/mundART_suche/?words=Freitag), [Såumsti](http://www.mundart.vulkanland.at/de/mundART_suche/?words=Samstag), [Sunndi](http://www.mundart.vulkanland.at/de/mundART_suche/?words=Sonntag)

(Die Links führen zur Seite des jeweiligen Wortes auf mundart.vulkanland.at. Dort ist detailliert angegeben, in welcher Gemeinde welche Variante in Verwendung ist.)

Dass die Endsilbe *»-ti«* bzw. *»-ta«* für *»tag«* steht, liegt auf auf der Hand, und fünf der 7 Namen haben auch erkennbare Ähnlichkeit mit den standarddeutschen Namen. Aber die Namen für Dienstag und Donnerstag stechen hervor, weil sie keine Ähnlichkeit mit standarddeutschen Wochentagsnamen haben. Leider finde ich nur sehr wenig über die Herkunft dieser beiden exotischen Wochentagsnamen.

Für den Dienstag findet man auf der erwähnten Website diese Bezeichnungen (in Klammern: Anzahl der Nennungen):

> Dienstag = Eachta (4); Eachti (2); Iachta (4); Iachti (4); Iadi (4); Iati (4); Irchti (1)

Die Vokalfolge "ia" am Beginn der meisten Varianten ist ein Diphthong, bei dem das *i* stark betont ist und das *a* als [Tiefschwa](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_offener_Zentralvokal) gesprochen wird.

Dasselbe für den Donnerstag:

> Donnerstag = G'fingsta (3), G'fingsti (8), G'pfingsta (1), Pfingsta (4), Pfingsti (11), Pfingsttog (1)

Ich habe herausgefunden, dass *»pfingstag«* bereits um 1400 im süddeutschen Raum verwendet wurde ([Quelle](https://fwb-online.de/go/pfingstag.s.0m_1646937633)), und sich offenbar in der Südoststeiermark bis heute gehalten hat. Aber ich habe bisher nicht herausfinden können, was der Teil *»pfing«* bedeuten könnte.

Ich habe nur eine Vermutung: Das Wort *»Pfingsten«* für das christliche Fest geht auf altgriechisch *»πεντηκοστὴ ἡμέρα« (pentekoste emera)* (der fünfzigste Tag) zurück, und der Donnerstag ist nach alter christlicher Zählung der fünfte Tag der Woche. Das wäre laut DeepL neugriechisch *»πέμπτη ημέρα« (pempti imera)*<sup>2</sup> und altgriechisch vermutlich recht ähnlich. Könnte sich *»pempti«* (bzw. dessen altgriechische Entsprechung), vielleicht unter dem Einfluss von *»Pfingsten«* zu *»pfingstag«* entwickelt haben?

Über die Herkunft von *Iadi* und seinen Varianten habe ich noch nichts herausgefunden. Kann mir jemand helfen?

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Vor 17 Millionen Jahren (im Miozän) und vor 2 Millionen Jahren (im Pliozän) waren dort, wo heute der Südosten der Steiermark liegt, mehrere Vulkane aktiv. Die erloschenen Vulkankegel bilden heute die Hügel des Steirischen Hügellandes und die noch immer existierenden Magmakammern im Untergrund sind die Ursache für die vielen Thermalquellen in dieser Region. Im Jahr 1999 kreierte man daher den Markennamen "Vulkanland" um diese Region touristisch besser zu vermarkten. Die dort lebende Bevölkerung identifiziert sich inzwischen mehrheitlich mit dieser Bezeichnung und ist sich meist gar nicht bewusst, dass es sich in Wahrheit um einen geschützten Markennamen handelt.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>Wie ich aus einem der unten stehenden Kommentare gelernt habe, wird »η« neugriechisch als »i« transliteriert, altgriechisch ist es »e«.</sub>

Comment: "Christliche Zählung" ist etwas strittig. Lt. Christentum schuf Gott Himmel und Erde am ersten Tag, ... und am 7. Tag ruhte er. Oder er schied Licht und Finsternis am 1. - ich glaube das war's. Jedenfalls ruhte er am 7., so dass das die logisch-christliche Zählung wäre, und auch heute, etwa bei den Katholiken, m.W. die übliche. Wie es zu der Idee kam, dass der So. der erste Tag der Woche war? Entweder, weil man ihn als hl. Tag herausheben wollte, und Fürst/first usw. oft wertend verstanden wird. Oder weil ja das alte Testament als Vermächtnis der Juden, den Sabbath, also Sa. als 7. Tag hatten.

Comment: @user unknown: In allen katholischen Klöstern gibt es zum Teil viele Jahrhunderte alte Stundenbücher, in denen die Stundengebete der Mönche und Nonnen niedergeschrieben sind. In den meisten dieser Bücher sind die Wochentage mit Buchstaben durchnummeriert. Dabei ist A=Sonntag, B=Montag, usw. bis G=Samstag. Daher beginnt die katholische Woche am Sonntag und endet am Samstag. Der vierte Tag in dieser Zählung bildet genau die Mitte der Woche und daher haben haben ihn die Christen im deutschsprachigen Raum "Mittwoch" genannt. (Davor hieß er Wotanstag, was den Christen gar nicht gepasst hat.)

Comment: Aber Thor (Donnerstag) und Freya (Freitag) haben's überlebt. :)

Comment: In der jüdisch-christlichen Tradition: Der siebte Tag, an dem laut AT Gott ruhte, ist der Sabbat/Samstag, also der jüdische Feiertag. Christus ist laut neuem Testament am Tag *nach dem Sabbat* auferstanden, wodurch der Tag nach dem Sabbat, also der erste Tag der Woche, zum Hauptfeiertag der Christen wurde. Die "christliche Zählung" würde ich da nicht als "strittig" bezeichnen, da gibt es ja eine klare Kontinuität. Der Montag als Wochenanfang ergibt sich aus der Arbeitswoche, viel viel später, erst 1975 wurde das in der entsprechenden DIN-Norm geändert.

Comment: Kleine Korrektur: das "Ita" ("η") wird im Neugriechischen wie "i" (in der Aussprache kein Unterschied zu Iota oder Ipsilon) ausgesprochen, deshalb: "pempti imera". Das "imera" wird auf der zweiten Silbe betont.

Comment: @bakunin: Danke für diesen Hinweis! Das ist mir eine zweite Fußnote in meiner Frage wert.

Answer (score 4):

Ertag und Pfinztag gehen z.B. laut Wikipedia ([Dienstag](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dienstag)/[Donnerstag](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donnerstag)), DWB ([Dienstag](https://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/dienstag)/[Donnerstag](https://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/donnerstag)) oder DWDS ([Dienstag](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Dienstag#etymwb-1)/[Donnerstag](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Donnerstag#etymwb-1)) auf die entsprechenden griechischen Namen Ἄρεως ἡμέρα ‘Ares-Tag’ (daraus via [interpretatio romana](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretatio_Romana) der Name *Mārtis diēs/martedì/mardi,* und daraus wiederum via [interpretation germanica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretatio_germanica) der Name *Tuesday/Ziestag,* und daraus als niederrheinische Nebenform *Dienstag)* bzw. πέμπτη ἡμέρα ‘fünfter Tag’ zurück, möglicherweise via gotische Übermittlung.

Comment: Auch https://bar.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_boarische_Wocha, aber ohne Zuordnung zu den Quellen.

Answer (score -1):

Die exakte Form *iadi* kann ohne Rückgriff auf griechische Vorlagen aus dem germanischen erklärt werden, da *j(e)-* in verschiedenen Pronomina einen für Aufzählungen geeignet zu sein scheinenden Anlaut bietet und *πέμπτη* im Vergleich entweder auf eine reine Zählung hinweist oder ein Idol namens "5."

Ergo, die Zusammenstellung der altgriechischen Woche ist offensichtlich inhomogen, deshalb ist die selbe grundlegende Annahme auch für die etwaige daraus abzuleitende Konstruktion sinnvoll, ohne die behauptete Entlehnung tatsächlich anzuerkennen, da *Iadi* und *Pfingsti* nicht zwingend aus *ein und dergleichen* Sprachschicht entlehnt sein müssen.

Als weiterer Vergleich bieten sich aus älterem Deutsch *ander* "zweiter" an, so dass in Böhmen gemeinslavisch **vъtorъ* "zweiter", **vъtorьnikъ*, **vъtorъkъ* "Dienstag" zu vergleichen sein dürfte (q.v. en.Wiktionary). Bemerkenswert ist an der Stelle, dass Mittelbayrisch ein Dualpronomen bewahrt hat, das ähnlich anklingt und ohne **-teros auskommt

Keltisch *yan* "eins" wäre schwieriger in die Nähe des heutigen Wien zu bringen, ist aber archäologisch insbesondere im Bezug auf den vermeintlichen Ursprung germanischer Runen (und damit später auch slavischer) aus mediterranen Schrifttypen über Alpine Alphabete relevant, sowie dementsprechend *er-ster*. In diesem Zeitrahmen ist schon mit verschiedenen Wocheneinteilungen zu rechnen. Dabei stellt Rückwärtszählung einen interessanten Sonderfall dar (der auch der Etymologien zu *elf, zwölf* unterstellt wird), womit angedeutet würde, dass der darauf folgende Tag besonders relevant ist.

PS: Vorstellbar kam es dabei zu Überlagerung mit *as-*, *Aesir* (Proto-Germanic **ansuz*) als eine alternative Übersetzung der allgemeineren Bedeutung von *Deus* "Gott" zu *Dies Iovis* (**djous patēr* < **dyḗws ph₂tḗr*. vorausgesetzt, s.v. en.WT: *Jove*), was um so mehr besticht, da römisch *as* als Münze kleinster Stückelung gilt und sicherlich zu Anfang von irgendeinem Gott geziert wurde. Wikipedia ([As (Roman coin)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As_(Roman_coin))) zeigt Examplare, die auf *Janus* als den zweigesichtigen Gott des Ein- und Ausgang hindeuten, mit dem tatsächlich der Monat *Jänner* als letzter und er-ster des Jahres benannt wird, aber wohl als *dualer* Monat eine Übergangsperiode bezeichnete.

Comment: Bezüglich Kelten: Die mussten nicht zum heutigen Wien reisen um die Sprache im Vulkanland zu beeinflussen, sondern ins Vulkanland. Aber sie waren ohnehin an beiden Orten, denn das [keltische Königreich Noricum](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noricum) erstreckte sich ziemlich genau auf dem Gebiet des heutigen Ost-Österreich (es gibt [keltische Funde im Vulkanland](http://archaeologie.vulkanland.at/archaeologie/deutsch/einleitung.htm)) und wurde nach der Eroberung durch die Römer zur römischen Provinz Noricum. Später vertrieben die ...

Comment: ... Hunnen die Römer aus dieser Gegend und danach siedelten sich dort Avaren, Slaven, Bajuwaren und Langobarden an. Gegen 800 n.Chr. kamen auch ein paar Franken. Dominierend waren aber die Bajuwaren, die das ehemalige Noricum als ihr "Ostland" oder "Ostreich" ansahen und ihm den Namen "Ostarrichi" gaben, woraus dann die beiden Namen "Austria" und "Österreich" entstanden.

Comment: @vectory Leider hört sich das alles an, als ob es ohne Rücksicht auf historische Belege und Lautgesetze, rein nach grober Homophonie, zusammengereimt wäre.  Z. B. kann mhd. erge(tac) nicht aus je, jan, ja, jo o. dgl. entstehen. Auch der Dual, der im GESAMTEN bairischen Sprachraum teilweise erhalten ist aber als Plural verwendet wird (bai. u. ahd. es, enk < germ. it, ink) hat nichts damit zu tun. Bei solchen Hypothesen wären daher Quellenangaben wichtig, wo die Details ausführlich diskutiert werden. Die Lehrmeinung ist das jedenfalls nicht.

Comment: @Shakesbeer, Der Dual PIE *-h1e* wie vermutlich in *Tür-e* ist außerdem weit über das bayrische Hinaus erhalten und die ursprüngliche Lautung ist ungewiss. Er- verhält sich problemlos wie "erst" (engl. *earl* usw.) analog zu "eins" unter der hypothese zu keltisch *yan*. Fakt ist, dass die Leermeinung zu *Tag* zweifelhaft ist. Um Methodenlehre ging es mir hier insofern gerade nicht, sondern um eine angemessense Portion Skepsis. Dabei habe ich tatsächlich fast mutwillig übersehen, dass das *r* ggf. einfach vokalisiert sein kann, und habe die Worte daher getrennt, denn dafür fehlt mir die Quelle.